# PyTorch installation for CUDA 12 on win10 64 bit

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, compatibility

I need to install PyTorch on my PC, which has CUDA Version: 12.0.

[The table for pytorch 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X13oS.png) in In [pytorch site](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/) shows only CUDA 11.7 CUDA 11.8 as options.

[previous versions of PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/) doesn't mention CUDA 12 anywhere either.

What would be the most straightforward way to proceed?

Do I need to use an NGC container or build PyTorch from source?

thanks,
Omer

Comment: You don't need to build or do anything. Simply install following the command. It will work

Comment: Hi @Mhasan502,
Do you mean the command for CUDA 11.7 or 11.8?
thanks

Comment: You can select any. [Pip wheels and Conda binaries ship with their own CUDA runtime](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/does-pytorch-use-the-cudatoolkit-in-docker-or-the-system/140303/2)

Answer (score 6):

One option is installing the nightly build that supports Python 3.11 and CUDA 12.1:

```
pip3 install --pre torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/nightly/cu121
```