# Unable to access NVIDIA GPU using Pytorch-cuda for CUDA version 12.2

Tags: pytorch, gpu, nvidia

I am having difficulty accessing my GPU to help train a YOLOv8 model. I have tried following the directions [here](https://thinkinfi.com/train-yolov8-on-custom-dataset-in-windows-gpu/), but have not been able to successfully access the GPU using pytorch-cuda and have also tried installing the nightly build for 12.2 using `pip3 install --pre torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/nightly/cu122` from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75956626/pytorch-installation-for-cuda-12-on-win10-64-bit). My GPU drivers are fully updated and I believe I have followed the instructions accurately, but have not been able to make progress.

I am new to GPU processing, so I would love any guidance on how to properly access my GPU to speed up my model training.

For background:

- I have windows 11
- I am using python 3.11.3
- I am trying to run YOLOv8 on my NVIDIA GPU
- I have an older (but supported) NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 with Max-Q Design
- My `!nvidia-smi` output can be seen here [image: nvidia-smi]
- Versions for ultralytics can be seen here [package-checks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7McUy.png)
- I am using conda to manage my environment and I am running code in a Jupyter Notebook that I open in VSCode

I tried installing pytorch-cuda for 12.2, 11.7, and 11.8, but was not able to access the GPU for any of them. I am using the code below as a test and it has continuously returned False.

```
import torch
torch.cuda.is_available()
```

Comment: I don't think https://download.pytorch.org/whl/nightly/cu122 exists yet. But https://download.pytorch.org/whl/nightly/cu121 does.